# My Google Sheets asks for Authentication with each copy made

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-oauth

I have a Google Sheet (multiple, actually), which has a Google App Script back-end to make some functionality on button presses and some triggers for onEdit and onLoad functionality. When I click on a button, it calls the appropriate function, but it asks for authentication first, telling me "This is not a verified app". I go through three prompts to authenticate (click on Ok, Advanced, Continue (unsafe), and Allow).

If I make a copy of that sheet, I have to go through the whole thing all over again. Users of these sheets have to do the same things.

How can I authenticate users who use those sheets without having to go through the above process? There must be a way I don't understand at the moment to do this.

Answer (score 2):

That's the normal process.  It's there to protect users that might get copies of  your container.  They get a choice about whether they wish to trust you or not.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use a [Google workspace addon](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/concepts/types). End users still need to authenticate, but you don't have to, for every copy made.
2. You can [publish a add on](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/how-tos/update-published-add-on) to the market, which doesn't need to be authenticated for every copy.